# Can I remove multiple indexes from a string with a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I am new to Python and I‘m currently just messing around a little bit... but I am stuck with this one problem. I am trying to remove certain indexes from a string with a for loop. My Idea was something like this:

```
Text="Gvusaibdsz8audvbsauzdgsavuczisagbcsuzaicbhas"
for i in range(0,7):
    Text=Text.replace(Text[i], "")
print(Text)
```

But it removes only one index and is restoring the already replaced ones, for example:

```
1.loop: vusaibdsz8audvbsauzdgsavuczisagbcsuzaicbhas
2.loop: Gusaibdsz8audvbsauzdgsavuczisagbcsuzaicbhas
```

Comment: variables should not start with uppercase chars :)

Answer (score 1):

Surely, there is many ways to get the desired result. Below, there is a good one based on your logic (using a `for loop`). As you are replacing a character by an empty character, It is better to directly remove the desired character.

In the code, I have transformed the `text` into a `list` for easy handling. After that, I have removed all characters based on the indexes. Finally, a join operation yields the desired `text`.

```
text = "Gvusaibdsz8audvbsauzdgsavuczisagbcsuzaicbhas"
text_list = list(text)
for index in range(0, 7):
    text_list.remove(text[index])

text = ''.join(text_list)
print(text)   # dsz8audvbsauzdgsavuczisagbcsuzaicbhas
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are trying to do, you are trying to omit letters of the string `Text` that are in indexes 0,1,2,3,4,5 and 6. but your code doesn't do that currently, but indeed it will take the first letter which is `G` and it will remove it from all the string(there is one occurrence), the next loop `Text` is equal to `u` because `Text` is equal vusaibdsz8audvbsauzdgsavuczisagbcsuzaicbhas after omitting `G` in the first iteration, as there are five occurrences of `u`, Text will be equal to `vsaibdsz8advbsazdgsavczisagbcszaicbhas` and so on..

you can put `print(Text)` inside the for loop and watch the results:

```
>>> Text="Gvusaibdsz8audvbsauzdgsavuczisagbcsuzaicbhas"
>>> for i in range(0,7):
...     Text=Text.replace(Text[i], "")
...     print(Text)
... 
vusaibdsz8audvbsauzdgsavuczisagbcsuzaicbhas
vsaibdsz8advbsazdgsavczisagbcszaicbhas
vsibdsz8dvbszdgsvczisgbcszicbhs
vsidsz8dvszdgsvczisgcszichs
vidz8dvzdgvczigczich
viz8vzgvczigczich
viz8vzvcziczich
```

In Python you can do that without a loop and the best way for that by using [slicing](https://railsware.com/blog/python-for-machine-learning-indexing-and-slicing-for-lists-tuples-strings-and-other-sequential-types/) as follows:

```
Text = Text[7:]
```

This will give you Text equal to `dsz8audvbsauzdgsavuczisagbcsuzaicbhas`.

If your goal is to reach this through a loop(supposing you are in need of Text in every iteration), you can try this:

```
>>> Text="Gvusaibdsz8audvbsauzdgsavuczisagbcsuzaicbhas"
>>> for i in range(0,7):
...     Text = Text[1:]
...     print(Text)
... 
vusaibdsz8audvbsauzdgsavuczisagbcsuzaicbhas
usaibdsz8audvbsauzdgsavuczisagbcsuzaicbhas
saibdsz8audvbsauzdgsavuczisagbcsuzaicbhas
aibdsz8audvbsauzdgsavuczisagbcsuzaicbhas
ibdsz8audvbsauzdgsavuczisagbcsuzaicbhas
bdsz8audvbsauzdgsavuczisagbcsuzaicbhas
dsz8audvbsauzdgsavuczisagbcsuzaicbhas
```

I hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at string [slicing](https://www.journaldev.com/23584/python-slice-string):

```
text = "Gvusaibdsz8audvbsauzdgsavuczisagbcsuzaicbhas"
newtext = text[1:]
print(newtext)
```

--> "Gvusaibdsz8audvbsauzdgsavuczisagbcsuzaicbhas"
--> "vusaibdsz8audvbsauzdgsavuczisagbcsuzaicbhas"

Answer (score 0):

You can replace

```
Text=Text.replace(Text[i], "")
```

with

```
Text = Text[:i] + Text[i+1:]
```

which uses slicing to rebuild a string without the specific index.

Side note: variable names should be lower case.

Comment: Great thanks a lot

Comment: That's wonderful. Could you accept this answer by clicking the checkmark.